# IdentityServer4 Hybrid flow API token unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 Hybrid flow so I have an MVC website that connects to IdentityServer, then this MVC website calls an API with the token return by IDS4. All is working well or almost. After some time I get an error from the API

> error 401 unauthorized

The token is refreshed before the call so for me it should work.

Locally it's working perfectly all the time, I only have an issue with the website on Azure. But if I connect with a private session from Chrome on Azure it's working again. So I think the issue is with Cookies somehow, but I don't know exactly what to do/try.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this?